# Zend_Form and data escaping

Tags: zend-framework

Do i have to use any sort of escaping functions like mysqli_real_escape_string() using Zend_Form when getting data from form's inputs prior to inserting data in db or is the data automatically escaped by zend for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get data for your Zend_Form instance, you can use 2 methods:

```
$form->getValues();
```

This one gives you filtered values.

```
$form->getUnfilteredValues();
```

This one will give you raw values inputted by user.

In Zend Framework, you don't have escaping by default, instead you should worry about it yourself.

Good rule for that would be "Filter input, escape output". If there is a chance of getting XSS or other type of vulnerabilities.

Use prepared statements to protect from injections and escape your data in views to protect from XSS.

Comment: So $form->getValues() runs all filters attached to that form elem? Right? If so is there some default filters added automatically for every text input element or there isn't any and i have to add every needed filter explicitly using addFilter()?